# Получение текущего местоположения

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, геолокация

Нужно получать текущее местоположение телефона в виде "London" - название города, "uk" - буквенный код страны, подскажите пожалуйста как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью гугловского [геокодера](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html) можно